# Filter the search result using time

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

Consider the elastic search documents in an index "orders/orders" representing different stages of an event

```
{"order_id": 10001, "order_status": "New",       "time": 20180524101505}
{"order_id": 10002, "order_status": "New",       "time": 20180524101505}
{"order_id": 10001, "order_status": "Paid",      "time": 20180524102505}
{"order_id": 10002, "order_status": "Cancelled", "time": 20180524111505}
{"order_id": 10001, "order_status": "shipped",   "time": 20180525082505}
{"order_id": 10003, "order_status": "New",       "time": 20180525101505}
{"order_id": 10001, "order_status": "Delivered", "time": 20180526082505}
{"order_id": 10001, "order_status": "Closed",    "time": 20180526082605}
```

How can I get perform a search in which the result will be the latest stage of that event. Basically what I needs to do is to sort based on the "time" and get the individual result

```
{"order_id": 10002, "order_status": "Cancelled", "time": 20180524111505}
{"order_id": 10001, "order_status": "Closed",    "time": 20180526082605}
{"order_id": 10003, "order_status": "New",       "time": 20180525101505}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `max` aggregation, I'd suggest using the `top_hits` one since you need to retrieve the latest document for each order:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "byOrderId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "order_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": {"time": "desc"},
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the same as using `max` what's the advantage of using `top_hits` with `size 1` ordering by `desc`, instead of `max` aggregation that as I understand does the same?

Comment: @jordivador `max` will only create a bucket for the latest timestamp, but you won't get any info about the document that contains the max timestamp (i.e. you won't see the `order_status` field, etc)

Comment: Oh I missed that he requires all information about each hit!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an aggregation by `orderId` using a [terms-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and then a sub-aggregation using [max-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html)

Here the example:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "byOrderId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "order_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "maxTime": {
          "max": {
            "field": "time"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As per the comment from @Val in the accepted answer: max will only create a bucket for the latest timestamp, but you won't get any info about the document that contains the max timestamp (i.e. you won't see the order_status field, etc)